# Best way to pass textures between MTKViews?

Tags: metal, metalkit

I have a situation I've been struggling with for some time.

Within a `draw:` call to an `MTKView`, I generate a `MTLTexture` which is part of a render chain to that view's drawable.  Now, I want to use that texture as a basis for drawing in a secondary `MTKView`.

To prevent animation stutter when tinkering with the app's menus, I have both views configured in explicit draw mode, with a `CVDisplayLink` dispatching these draw calls into a serial queue (ie. not on the main thread).  I've even tried configuring the secondary view to draw on the main queue with setNeedsDisplay.

I can get this to mostly work, though due to what I suspect is some threading issues, I receive an occasional crash.  I've even go so far as to place the draw calls to these two `MTKViews` successively on the same *serial* thread (via `dispatch_queue_async`) without much success.  I've also tried placing a generated `MTLTexture` into a little semaphore-protected FIFO queue that the secondary view consumes from -- again, without much success.

Things will run swimmingly well for a few minutes with full-motion video frames as the source, then I receive a crash whilst in the `draw` method of the second view.  Typically, this is what happens when I go to retrieve the texture:

```
id<MTLTexture>inputTexture = [textureQueue firstObject];
// EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40dedeadbec8)
```

Occasionally, I will end up bailing on the draw as the texture is `MTLTextureType1D` (instead of 2D) or its usage is erroneously only `MTLTextureUsageShaderRead`.  And yet my `MTLTextureDescriptor` is fine; like I say, 99.99% of the time, things work swimmingly well.

**I wondering if someone can assist with the proper, thread-safe way of obtaining a texture in one `MTKView` and passing it off to a secondary `MTKView` for subsequent processing.**

Comment: Serializing the command encoding and submission on the CPU is a separate concern from ensuring you don't access resources incorrectly on the GPU. In order to use a texture produced by one command buffer in a subsequent command buffer, you should at least wait until the first command buffer is scheduled (e.g. by adding a scheduled handler and signaling your semaphore from there). Assuming you're submitting all your work from the same thread (even if it isn't the main thread), do you see correct behavior if you call `waitUntilComplete` on the first command buffer before encoding to the second?

Comment: That's a great point, warrenm, ...that may be the ticket.  I imagine a possibly more elegant alternative is the use a MTLFence update/wait on the first encoder.

Comment: I tried awaiting until the command buffer from the first view was scheduled; that didn't help.  Now doing `waitUntilComplete` on both command buffers with apparent success!  Thanks, @warrenm

Comment: If I recall your earlier questions, you're creating textures from video sources (AVFoundation, CoreVideo, or whatever). I think the problem is keeping textures that that subsystem owns while not retaining the "container" object that vended it for the same duration. The texture may be returned to a pool and reused while you're still holding it.

Comment: @KenThomases. The original texture from AVFoundation is at the beginning of the render chain.  There are many render passes to manipulate that original texture into its final state for presenting as a drawable.  Each "pass" generates a new texture on-the-fly... passing one of these textures onto an alternate `MTKView` was causing the issue.  Hence, it appears I need to `waitUntilComplete` with these newly-formed textures.

Comment: You shouldn't have to `waitUntilCompleted`. That's a brute force, overkill approach. I think Warren only suggested it as a diagnostic step. It's an interesting result, but trying to use it as the "solution" will just hide the real problem. Show the stack trace of the crash. Run your app under the Zombies Instrument template and see what it finds.